# Recursive Makefile Does Not Recognize Dependency Changes in Sub-Directory

Tags: makefile

I am aware that there is a lot of debate around recursive makefiles. That being understood, I'm still trying to get one to work.

**Context:** I have the following project setup:

```
quendor
  src
    zmachine
      Makefile
      main.c
      zmachine.h
  Makefile
```

So I use the root-level `Makefile` to call another `Makefile` in a directory. (My actual project has other directories that generate other library files but, for now, the above showcases the problem with the minimum amount of context.

The makefile setup I have in place does work in that it generates `.o` and `.d` files in the `zmachine` directory. Then a library (`zmachine.a`) is built correctly.

**Problem:** The problem I have is that when I run the makefile at the root level again, it will not pick up if there have been changes to either the `.c` or `.h` files in the subdirectory. I just get this message:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `zmachine_lib'.
```

**Example of My Code:**

Here is the root level `Makefile`:

```
CC := gcc

ifeq ($(CC), gcc)
    CFLAGS += -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -MMD -MP
    LDFLAGS +=
    OPT +=
endif

AR ?= $(shell which ar)
RANLIB ?= $(shell which ranlib)

export CC
export AR
export RANLIB
export CFLAGS

SRC_DIR = src

ZMACHINE_DIR = $(SRC_DIR)/zmachine
ZMACHINE_LIB = $(ZMACHINE_DIR)/zmachine.a

SUB_DIRS = $(ZMACHINE_DIR)

SUB_CLEAN = $(SUB_DIRS:%=%-clean)

# Targets

zmachine_lib : $(ZMACHINE_LIB)

$(ZMACHINE_LIB):
    $(MAKE) -C $(ZMACHINE_DIR)

clean : $(SUB_CLEAN)

$(SUB_CLEAN):
    -$(MAKE) -C $(@:%-clean=%) clean
```

Here is the `Makefile` from the `zmachine` directory:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)

DEPS := $(OBJECTS:%.o=%.d)

TARGET = zmachine.a

ARFLAGS = rc

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $?
    $(RANLIB) $@
    @echo "** Finished building Z-Machine architecture."

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -c $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPS)

-include $(DEPS)
```

Again, the logic of the Makefiles works in terms of generating the correct output and library files. So I seem to have got that part right.

What I can't get to work is having the combined Makefiles, working together, recognize that changes have been made and thus recompiling is necessary.

For example, if I change `main.c` or `zmachine.h`, running `make` again won't recognize that the change has happened, thus no recompilation is trigered.

**What I Tried:**

I did some searching for "recursive makefiles dependencies" and related searches but I couldn't find anything that showed me how to handle dependency changes in this specific context.

I did try running `make -d` to look at the files and dates that `make` was using. It gave me this output, which wasn't as helpful to me:

```
 No implicit rule found for `zmachine_lib'.
  Considering target file `src/zmachine/zmachine.a'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `src/zmachine/zmachine.a'.
  No need to remake target `src/zmachine/zmachine.a'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `zmachine_lib'.
Must remake target `zmachine_lib'.
Successfully remade target file `zmachine_lib'.
make: Nothing to be done for `zmachine_lib'.
```

I realize this must be because I do not have the file set up to recognize what depends on what. But I feel I do with this:

```
zmachine_lib : $(ZMACHINE_LIB)

$(ZMACHINE_LIB):
    $(MAKE) -C $(ZMACHINE_DIR)
```

Here zmachine_lib is the only target in this example. It depends on `$(ZMACHINE_LIB)` which, as you can see, I have set up to call the Makefile in the subdirectory.

So I'm guessing it's this bit of calling `$(MAKE)` that is perhaps obfuscating changes made at the subdirectory level since, for the `$(ZMACHINE_LIB`) target would appear to be already satisfied (from the perspective of the top-level Makefile).

I did find this [makefile with dependency on a shared library sub project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653483/makefile-with-dependency-on-a-shared-library-sub-project), which does seem like it's very close to my issue. But I can't see how to utilize that solution in my case because of the fact that the logic is distributed over the two Makefiles. I did try to change my target in the sub-Makefile to this:

```
$(TARGET): $(SOURCES)
  ...
```

Basically changing `$(OBJECTS)` to `$(SOURCES)`, which is what it seems like that other solution was suggesting. But that does not work for me; dependency changes are still not recognized.

Comment: Yep, indeed there are. When I run the makefile, the following files are created in the subdirectory: `main.o`, `main.d`, and `zmachine.a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am aware that there is a lot of debate around recursive makefiles.

I'm not sure there is so much *debate*, really.  Recursive `make` has some pretty well known limitations.  Non-recursive `make` has different, largely complementary, limitations.

> That being understood, I'm still trying to get one to work.

Lots of people do.  But although you may understand that recursive `make` has known issues, you do not seem to understand their nature, because you are asking about a manifestation of one of main ones.

> **Problem**: The problem I have is that when I run the makefile at the root level again, it will not pick up if there have been changes to
> either the .c or .h files in the subdirectory.

No, it doesn't.  That is to be expected with your makefile.

Recursive `make` serves large projects by dividing build information into more manageable pieces and keeping it close to the sources being built.  Among the main costs of doing so is that details, especially dependency details, are compartmentalized.  In your case, the top-level `make` knows that a target `src/zmachine/zmachine.a` is to be built, but no dependencies for that target are known to it.  As a result, *that* `make` considers the target out of date only if it does not exist.  So yes, it will not recognize that target as being out of date relative to its actual sources.  That a sub-`make` would update it if run is irrelevant, because the sub-`make` never runs.

The usual, more practicable approach to recursive `make` is to recurse *unconditionally*.  Something like this:

```
SUBDIRS = src doc

all: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
        $(MAKE) -C $@
```

Where there are dependencies among the targets managed by different `make` runs, those still need to be modeled somehow, else you will sometimes need multiple runs of the overall `make` for everything to be updated.  Ideally, that's handled on a directory-by-directory basis, not a specific-target basis.

But that's a bit oversimplified, I'm afraid, because one generally wants recursion to work for most or all top-level targets, not just for the default target.  You should consider looking at someone else's working recursive `make` build system to see how they do it.

Comment: This is good info, thank you! The context is very helpful. I have looked at other projects that seem to do recursive make, but it was hard to tell at a glance if they worked any better than mine. In fact, mine is cribbed from a few examples of recursive make examples I found on GitHub. After seeing the issues with mine, I found those project had the same issue. They just didn't bring it up.

Comment: So now I'm wondering if I should just merge my makefiles and find a way to do everything from the one makefile. To get around that file being too large, I could presumably use the `include` ability.

Comment: @JeffNyman, I, myself, am a proponent of non-recursive `make`, at least mostly, and especially for smaller projects.  As projects get larger, I tend to try to modularize via makefile `include` files instead of via recursive `make`.  Non-recursive `make` is definitely doable for projects with a lot of structure. Under some circumstances, however, it may make sense to mix recursive and non-recursive approaches to handling subdirectories.

Comment: Just to note, you need to mark the directories as `.PHONY` (or force them somehow).

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually marking John's answer as *the* answer, but I figured I would include one of my own as well.

I found the following [How can I get the dependencies of a target in a recursive makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312780/how-can-i-get-the-dependencies-of-a-target-in-a-recursive-makefile) which has the perfect solution in a sense:

"Rewrite it to be non-recursive or just live with it."

That pretty much is it, really. But live with *what*? Of all the material out there that seems to belabor the points, none seem to just state simply what would probably most help people like myself coming across this. To wit:

*Calling one makefile from within another makefile (i.e., using recursive make build process) can be ineffective and inefficient because neither makefile will have the full overview of dependencies. This means the only way you can make sure your compilation is fully up to date with all changes is to do a `make clean`, effectively rebuilding the project each time.*

Had I seen *that*, I would have known immediately that what I was dealing with was something that simply isn't possible. And while there are solutions that you can attempt, most of those will really just be introducing other problems. Which then goes back to that simple comment: "Rewrite it to be non-recursive or just live with it."

Examples of *how* to rewrite it non-recursively would also probably go a long way.

Comment: To make it non-recursive, you mostly just need to include proper relative paths in your target and prerequisite names in the rules in your (one) makefile.  Especially so if you're making good use of `make`'s automatic variables, which you do seem to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing what I think is one other possible answer to this. I'm finding that if I put the following in my root-level Makefile:

```
.PHONY : $(ZMACHINE_LIB)
```

It seems to work. Specifically, with that, let's say I start fresh -- no files generated. Then I do:

```
make zmachine_lib
```

That correctly compiles everything in the `zmachine` directory and builds the library `zmachine.a` Then if I run that same command again:

```
make zmachine_lib
```

I get:

```
'zmachine.a' is up to date
```

Perfect. That makes sense. Nothing changed, so everything is up to date.

Now I make a change to the `main.c` file in the `zmachine` directory and try again:

```
make zmachine_lib
```

Sure enough! The change is recognized and recompilation takes place. The same thing happens if I change `zmachine.h`.

So it looks like just treating the `$(ZMACHINE_LIB)` as a phony target forces the `makefile` in the subdirectory to actually be read -- even if `zmachine.a` exists.

I don't know if what I'm doing is considered bad practice here but I read the oft-mentioned [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://www.real-linux.org.uk/recursivemake.pdf) and it seems the situation is a little more nuanced than just saying "recursive makefiles are harmful." That said, I can see why people take the stance they do. (Actually, I can see it on both sides of the issue.)